# Grabbing file from Rails public directory via URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have read that everything stored within the `public` directory is literally publically accessible to everyone on the web.  I am having trouble trying to reproduce this.

**Example**

I store a file: `test.txt` inside the `public` directory.  I run `rails s` to boot up my server in the development environment, and I would think I can access that file by typing in the following URL:

```
localhost:3000/public/test.txt
```

That does not work though.  Any suggestions about what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out.  Do not put in `public` in the url:

```
localhost:3000/test.txt
```